# geth testnet node killed after a while

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

My geth testnode somehow always killed itself after a while. What happened and how can I make it continue running?

Here are the screenshots
[image]
[image]
...skipped some in-between synchronization lines...
[image]

Here is the synchronisation status of my node, somehow my current block is always 659842 (it was last evening when it is killed and same this morning).
[image]

I run my geth in a docker container through a script, the script is as below

`geth --testnet --datadir /root/.ethereum/ --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --etherbase 0 --unlock "$(cat /root/.ethereum/geth/security/coinbase)" --password /root/.ethereum/geth/security/password.sec`

As this is a dev / testr instance, I didn't secure any port. Is my instance "killed" by some external party? Is there some sort of housekeeping protocol imposed by ropsten on participating nodes?

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: I allocated 3GB to docker. I don't think it is memory issue, I have another docker that sync the maiinnet using the same docker config and it doesn't have the same issue

Comment: Can you take a look at the system log and/or use verbose logs in geth?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: the problem goes away after I increased the memory allocation to docker, try anywhere from 4 to 6GB. I suspect the different behaviours between mainnet and my own testnet is that I will never be able to successfully mine any block in mainnet.

Comment: this problem is due to memory error, but how to solve this without increasing memory is still not found